# Netty does not close a channel

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I have a strange problem with an application using `netty 3.6.2`. The application maintains connection with many clients, everything works fine, but after some time (around 2 hours) client disconnections are not handled properly. Despite invoking `channel.close()` method by the application, the channel is not closed and the `channelClosed` method of the `SimpleChannelHandler` is not triggered. I am completely sure that the `close()` method is invoked on the `channel` but somehow netty does not close the channel. I am a little bit confused because I can't find any exceptions in the logs. Can anybody give me a clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Netty do that asynchronously, you could check if the IO thread is busy or not by take a stack dump. Or you could just debug to see if something blocked it.